# Ionic 2 : Access to a variable value from a provider or page

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, typescript, ionic2

I have a problem in Ionic 2 and maybe one of you could help me out.
Basically, I have a provider that i'm building which includes the function BLE. I include this provider in one my page. And from this page I can call the function without problem. But what I want, is to access the public variable that is the provider. This variable is a status connection (true or false) and I want to access it from my page to know if I'm connected with BLE or not.

here's my code

BleProvider.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class BleProvider {

public isConnected:boolean;

constructor(public http: Http) {
 console.log('Hello BleProvider Provider');
}

connectToDevice(device){
 this.isConnected = true;
}
}
```

My page Login.ts

```
import { BleProvider } from '../../providers/ble/ble'
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-login',
templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
@NgModule({
providers: [BleProvider],
})

export class LoginPage {

constructor(public ble: BleProvider){
 ble.connectToDevice();
}

function testIsConnected(){
console.log("isConnected value: " + this.ble.isConnected);
}
}
```

The console.log will return "isConnected value: undefined. And if i set isConnected in the constructor of the provider (e.g. this.isConnected = false) even that the function connectToDevice will set isConnected at true, when i call it from my page it will return the value false.
Can someone explain to me what happens and how to solve this?

Comment: doesn't your typescript compiler throw error for not providing the ```device``` argument for connectToDevice function ?

Comment: I suggest you run the connecToDevice method in your ngOnInit implementation

Comment: How are you calling testIsConnected method ?  Check if your LoginPage constructor getting called ? You first need to create/initiate LoginPage object and BleProvider object. 
let ble = new BleProvider();
let loginPage = new LoginPage(ble);
loginPage.testIsConnected();
//this should printout right value of isConnected variable.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to my comment above. I think this would work for you.

```
constructor(public ble: BleProvider){
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.ble.connectToDevice()
}
```

I hope that helps.